# Excel Macro Recorder code results in error 438

Tags: excel, vba

I used the Excel macro recorder to record the VBA used to rotate a Chart Legend vertically.
It recorded:

```
Sub Macro1() 

' Macro1 Macro 
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate 
    ActiveChart.Legend.Select 
    Selection.Orientation = xlUpward    '<--- generates error
End Sub
```

However, if I attempt to run this macro it throws an error:
Run-Time error '438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.'
It makes no difference to specify -4171 for the xlUpward constant.

Oddly, the Orientation property is not listed as a property of the Chart Legend object (via Object Browser).

Does anyone know how to rotate a chart legend to be vertical via VBA?

Comment: Try working with the actual chart object instead of `Selection`: `Set theChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1")`; then you can access `theChart.Legend.Orientation` directly. Make sure you have _Show hidden members_ checked in the object browser, too.

Comment: tried theChart.Legend.Orientation = xlUpward  returned same 438 error
tried theChart.Legend.Orientation = -4171  returned same 438 error
searched object browser with Show Hidden Members; legend still does not show Orientation property but thanks for the suggestions.